# Should I avoid public networks firewall exception (Windows) when running Spring or other Java network applications?

Tags: spring-boot, security

I've been selecting only private networks recently because I realized if I'm testing apps on the go... I might end up offering my services to unknown users on public networks.
Is that sound reasoning? It is however one more step every time I Run a new app... which is quite often

I work on Restful webservices.

[EDIT] Some of what I needed to know is here but I didn't find it clear in the context of Some newb developer like myself hosting java applications on their personal computer. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189880/should-i-allow-communication-on-public-networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this old Microsoft crap.

Just press Cancel, and you're fine. The effect of pressing Cancel (yes, pressing Cancel really *does* something in this dialog) is that the firewall will allow connections from localhost to localhost, and that's usually all you need.

I, like many others, don't know a way of avoiding these annoying Windows questions. It would be so easy to "allow anything from localhost to localhost", but that seems to be impossible.